# ROS Rviz visualization of Tango Pose data

Tags: opengl, quaternions, ros, google-project-tango, coordinate-transformation

We have modified [sample code for the C API](https://github.com/googlesamples/tango-examples-c) so Tango pose data (position `(x,y,z)` and quaternion `(x,y,z,w)`) is published as PoseStamped ROS messages.

We are attempting to visualize the pose using Rviz. The pose data appears to need some transformation as the rotation of the Rviz arrow does not match the behavior of the Tango when we move it around.

We realize that in the sample code, before visualization on the Tango screen, [the pose data is transformed into a 4x4 Pose matrix](https://github.com/googlesamples/tango-examples-c/blob/master/cpp_point_cloud_example/app/src/main/jni/pose_data.cc) (function `PoseData::GetExtrinsicsAppliedOpenGLWorldFrame`), which is then multiplied left and right by various matrices representing changes of coordinate frames (for instance, Tango to OpenGL).

Ideally, we would be able to apply a similar transformation to the pose data before publishing it for visualization. However we must keep the pose data in the position `(x,y,z)` and quaternion `(x,y,z,w)` format in order to publish it in a PoseStamped message, and we do not see what transform to apply.

We have looked at the [Tango coordinate systems conventions](https://developers.google.com/project-tango/overview/coordinate-systems) but the transformations the Tango developers suggest we apply are only suited for pose data in a Pose matrix format. We have also attempted to apply transformations applied by [Ologic in their code](https://github.com/ologic/Tango/blob/master/ROSTango/src/rostango/TangoNodes/src/main/java/com/ologicinc/rostango/TangoNodes/vio/VioNode.java) to no avail.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to transform Tango pose data, without changing its format, for correct visualization on the Rviz OpenGL interface?

Answer (score 0):

If it's OpenGL convention, you will basically need to do a transformation on the left hand side of the pose data. The c++ motion tracking example has a line doing this operation [here](https://github.com/googlesamples/tango-examples-c/blob/master/cpp_motion_tracking_example/app/src/main/jni/scene.cc#L102). You could ignore the rotation part, but just apply following code:

```
glm::mat4 opengl_world_T_opengl_camera = tango_gl::conversions::opengl_world_T_tango_world() * start_service_T_deivce;
```

Answer (score 0):

I know that is a late answer but it can maybe help others people.
If you want to visualize any data with Rviz, I assume that you want to use ros. Then maybe the best way to do it is to use the rasjava library to do your Tango android app. It works well for me. I you just have to use poseStamp, odometry and tf publisher on your tango device and then display the topic with rviz. Morever it is one of the best way to keep the real-time aspect.

Moreover here there is 2 good way to learn how to use rosjava :

https://github.com/ologic/Tango

https://github.com/rosjava/android_core/tree/master